# Clever way to use 1 html-template for multiple applications in Flex Builder?

Tags: flexbuilder

The html-template portion of Flex Builder is currently only limited to 1 template. This works fine when you only have 1 application, but I have several applications in one project, each of which takes different flashParams.

I was wondering if anyone thought of a clever way of using 1 template to be used by multiple apps. So far, the only thing I can think of is to just place the embed code for each app in the html-template, and have it hidden by default, with links to enable.

Any other ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just doing what I mentioned in my original post. I simply placed embed code for each app in the html-template, and set them all to hidden by default. To enable one, I simply have javascript links at the header of the page for each app.